# There are no 'DS.MODEL.find' method in ember data Tag: v1.0.0-beta.2?

Tags: ember-data

I'd like to use didLoad callback for 'DS.MODEL.FIND', but can not find 'DS.MODEL.FIND' method in below webpage. 
Also can not find "findQuery", Thanks.

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html

Answer (score 0):

`find` and similar methods should be called from the store now.

For example, if you have a model `App.Post` you can look up the record with id 1 in a route or controller with:

```
this.store.find('post', 1)
```

Instead of how you would in 0.13:

```
App.Post.find(1)
```

Also, I recommend using the latest build as there have been a lot of fixes since beta 2.